# Having problems launching my glassfish server

Tags: intellij-idea, jax-rs, glassfish-5

I followed a starting guide for jax-rs web service development with intellij,glassfish. After i done the tutorial i tried to launch it as shown in tutorial, but server launched and atemmpted to start domain for a while and the website did not load. So I stopped the server and got error message at the bottom on the screen: http://prntscr.com/nsrmeb. Moreover here is how i start my application.

Tried restarting it couple times also searching in web for similar problems, but failed to find anything.

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application{
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses(){
    HashSet h = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    h.add(MatchResource.class);
    return h;
}
}
```

This is how the tutorial I followed: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first- 
restful-web-service.html

Comment: Please [contact support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) with the logs and the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) attached. Also specify your Glassfish server version.

Comment: The problem was in the version of jdk i've used.